# Facebook PHP SDK access token issue when retrieve User Profile via the Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have trying to retrieve user profile in my website.
But after I get the access token, I can't use it. The result it show is

```
Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token
```

I can get the access token by below code

**Login.php**

```
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'I have insert correct app id',
  'app_secret' => 'and app secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.0',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://myweb.com/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

And below is **login-callback.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'I have insert correct app id',
  'app_secret' => 'and app secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.0',
  ]);

  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

  try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }

  if (! isset($accessToken)) {
    if ($helper->getError()) {
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
      echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
      echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
      echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
    } else {
      header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
      echo 'Bad request';
    }
    exit;
  }

  $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

  try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', "'".$_SESSION['fb_access_token']."'");
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }

  $user = $response->getGraphUser();

  echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
  ?>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the access token to the `get` method yourself? Normally, the SDK should be able to handle this on its own, once you got a valid access token it stores it itself for future use.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  but how should I retrieve user profile by the access token? I just want to get the user data by using "get" method with access token @CBroe

Comment: Simply `$fb->get('/me?fields=id,name')` should work perfectly fine, if you have made the SDK get a user access token before.

Comment: It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only have:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $token);
$user = $response->getGraphUser();
```

It works perfectly

Comment: Where can i get that 'token'?

Answer (score 2):

I think You should change your code : 
       `"'".$_SESSION['fb_access_token']."'"`   to   `$accessToken` 
and try again